# Can't build cordova projects

Tags: java, android, cordova, netbeans

I have a problem with setting up the work environment for Cordova on Windows 7 for Android. I use NetBeans 8 and followed this guide: [Link Here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/cordova-gettingstarted.html.) 
New project -> Cordova -> Hello World Template.

Whenever I try to build a Cordova project (in NetBeans) I get this message:

```
    BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HTML5Application2\platforms\android\build.xml:90: Cannot find C:\Users\Administrator\SkyDrive\Skolegang\DataingeniÃ¸r\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml imported from C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HTML5Application2\platforms\android\build.xml

Total time: 0 seconds

C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HTML5Application2\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HTML5Application2\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HTML5Application2\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
Command finished with error code 8: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HTML5Application2\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat --emulator
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HTML5Application2\nbproject\build.xml:272: exec returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 47 seconds)
```

I have googled it for hours but can't seem to find a solution. Some people get some of the same errors(not exact, but similar), but the solutions did not work for me. One issue was regarding Java 8 and ant versions beneath 1.9.0 (I use Node 0.10.26, java 1.7.0_25, cordova 3.5.0-0.2.4 and ant 1.9.4). I also tried to create a new project with the console (CMD), but it gives the exact same error when I build. It's no problem to create the project, nor adding Android as a platform, the problem is building the project. I think the environment variables are set correctly since the java, node, ant and cordova commands work fine in cmd/powershell, and the `check_reqs.bat` said that the environment was fine.

It's this line that creates the error: `<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />`. This is the rest of the message: `Cannot find C:\Users\Administrator\SkyDrive\Skolegang\DataingeniÃ¸r\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml imported from C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HTML5Application2\platforms\android\build.xml.`

Here is the error I get in the command window (not using NetBeans):

PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\fakeApp> cordova build android

```
Running command: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\fakeApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat
Buildfile: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\fakeApp\platforms\android\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\fakeApp\platforms\android\build.xml:90: Cannot find C:\Users\Administrator\SkyDrive\
Skolegang\Dataingeni├©r\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml imported from C:\Users\Admini
strator\Desktop\test\fakeApp\platforms\android\build.xml

Total time: 0 seconds
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\fakeApp\platforms\androi
d\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\fakeApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\s
rc\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I thought maybe it was a path issue since I have a special letter in the path were the NetBeansProjects are stored (and it's pretty long too), but creating a test directory at C:\ and creating the project with the command window gave the same error. I'm new at Cordova so I'm sure there's an easy solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does ant path exist in your env variables?

Comment: Yes, it's added to the environment variable Path like this: C:\Program Files (x86)\Ant\bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, though I tried to create a cordova project outside the OneDrive folder I did not think of the SDK path (which also were stored in OneDrive). By moving the SDK files to C: (the path could probably not contain the special letter 'ø') and changing the path of the environment variables (and the SDK path in NetBeans) it now runs perfectly.