# How to execute an Meteor+Cordova tutorial (like SoLoMo) on my Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, adb, meteor-cordova

My goal is to develop an android app, which has a survey like functionality. So I experiment with Meteor and Cordova (also to learn the frameworks).

My substep: Running one of the tutorials on my Android device: Samsung Galaxy S3 fails.

That's how I start the app, while being in the directory **/var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo**:

```
meteor run android-device -p 192.168.178.21:3000 --verbose
```

Here are the last lines from the --verbose log:

```
-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...
-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache
-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...
-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...
-post-package:
-do-debug:
     [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
-post-build:
debug:
-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found new input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.
-pre-compile:
     [echo] Set jars path to: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
I20150629-10:36:48.553(2)? - waiting for device -
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
    [javac] 3 warnings
-post-compile:
-obfuscate:
-dex:
      [dex] input: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
      [dex] input: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-4340c49ff3fe08c4129acefebb6bbc29.jar <- /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
      [dex] Found modified input file
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/classes.dex...
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://192.168.178.21:3000/
       [dx] Merged dex A (94 defs/130,6KiB) with dex B (207 defs/313,5KiB). Result is 301 defs/539,9KiB. Took 0,8s
-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png => /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/res/drawable-land-hdpi/screen.png => /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-land-hdpi/screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-land-hdpi/screen.png: 27% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/res/drawable-land-ldpi/screen.png => /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-land-ldpi/screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-land-ldpi/screen.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/res/drawable-land-mdpi/screen.png => /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-land-mdpi/screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-land-mdpi/screen.png: 38% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png => /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png: 34% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png => /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png => /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png: 26% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/res/drawable-port-ldpi/screen.png => /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-port-ldpi/screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-port-ldpi/screen.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/res/drawable-port-mdpi/screen.png => /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-port-mdpi/screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-port-mdpi/screen.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.png => /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.png: 34% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png => /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Crunched 11 PNG files to update cache
-package-resources:
     [aapt] Found modified input file
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...
     [aapt] Warning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines debuggable (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest.
-package:
[apkbuilder] Found modified input file
[apkbuilder] Creating solomo-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
-post-package:
-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
     [echo] Debug Package: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/solomo-debug.apk
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
-post-build:
     [move] Moving 1 file to /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build
     [move] Moving 1 file to /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build
debug:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 31 seconds
/var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to install apk to device: ERROR: Failed to deploy to device, no devices found.
Command finished with error code 8: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run --device
Error: /var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)

Could not start the app on your device. Is it plugged in?
Try running again with the --verbose option.
Instructions for running your app on an Android device:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-run-your-app-on-an-Android-device
tokam@localhost:/var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo$ adb devices
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: 
tokam@localhost:/var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo$ 
tokam@localhost:/var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo$ 
tokam@localhost:/var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo$ clear

tokam@localhost:/var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo$ killall adb
tokam@localhost:/var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo$ adb devices > /tmp/log
tokam@localhost:/var/www/node_development/tutorials/solomo$ meteor run android-device -p 192.168.178.21:3000 --verbose > /tmp/log 
%% Parsing the --port option
%% Will compile mobile builds
%% Running build for platforms: [ 'android' ]
%% Building the cordova build project
%% Bundling the web.cordova program of the app
%% Ensuring the cordova build project
%% Reading the mobile control file
%% Running the mobile control file
%% Copying resources for mobile apps
%% Writing new config.xml
%% Ensuring that platforms in cordova build project are in sync
%% Running synchronously:  /home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/cordova.sh [ 'platform', 'list' ]
%% The output of `cordova platforms list`: Installed platforms: android 3.5.1
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, firefoxos, ubuntu

%% The platform is not in the Cordova project: ios
%% Ensuring plugins in the cordova build project are in sync { 'org.apache.cordova.console': '0.2.10',
  'org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser': '0.5.1',
  'org.apache.cordova.geolocation': '0.3.10',
  'org.apache.cordova.camera': '0.3.2',
  'org.apache.cordova.file': '1.3.0',
  'org.apache.cordova.file-transfer': '0.4.4',
  'org.apache.cordova.device': '0.2.11',
  'com.meteor.cordova-update': 'https://github.com/meteor/com.meteor.cordova-update/tarball/92fe99b7248075318f6446b288995d4381d24cd2',
  'org.apache.cordova.statusbar': '0.1.7',
  'org.apache.cordova.splashscreen': '0.3.3' }
%% Getting installed plugins for project
%% Running synchronously:  /home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/cordova.sh [ 'plugin', 'list' ]
%% The output of `cordova plugins list`: com.meteor.cordova-update 0.0.1 "CordovaUpdate"
org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.2 "Camera"
org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.10 "Console"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.11 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.0 "File"
org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.4.4 "File Transfer"
org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.10 "Geolocation"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.5.1 "InAppBrowser"
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen 0.3.3 "Splashscreen"
org.apache.cordova.statusbar 0.1.7 "StatusBar"

%% Will check for cordova-tarball-plugins.json for tarball-url-based plugins previously installed.
%% The tarball plugins lock: { 'com.meteor.cordova-update': 'https://github.com/meteor/com.meteor.cordova-update/tarball/92fe99b7248075318f6446b288995d4381d24cd2' }
%% Copying the JS/CSS files one level up
%% Removing the www folder
%% Writing www/application folder
%% Writing index.html
%% Writing meteor_cordova_loader
%% Writing a default index.html for cordova app
%% Running the build command
%% Running synchronously:  /home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/cordova.sh [ '--verbose', 'build', 'android' ]
%% Done building the cordova build project
%% A run on a device requested
WARNING: You are testing your app on a remote device.
         For the mobile app to be able to connect to the local server, make
         sure your device is on the same network, and that the network
         configuration allows clients to talk to each other
         (no client isolation).

WARNING: It looks like you are using OAuth2 login in your app.
         Meteor's OAuth2 implementation does not currently work with
         mobile apps in local development mode, except in the iOS
         simulator. You can run the iOS simulator with 'meteor run ios'.
         For additional workarounds, see
         https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/OAuth-for-mobile-Meteor-clients.

%% Execing cordova for platform android-device
%% isDevice: true
%% Running emulator: /home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/cordova.sh [ 'run', '--verbose', '--device', 'android' ]
%% Running asynchronously:  /home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/cordova.sh [ 'run', '--verbose', '--device', 'android' ]
%% Clearing logs for Android with `adb logcat -c`, should time-out in 5 seconds
%% Running asynchronously:  /home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/adb.sh [ 'logcat', '-c' ]
%% adb logcat -c timed out
%% Clearing logs failed: Error: clearing logs of Android device timed out: adb logcat -c
    at Object.Future.wait (/home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
    at execCordovaOnPlatform (/home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/commands-cordova.js:1216:14)
    at _.extend.start (/home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/commands-cordova.js:914:7)
    at /home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-all.js:160:23
    at /home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:313:18
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:312:36
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:303:26)
    at /home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-all.js:159:22
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at _.extend.start (/home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-all.js:156:7)
    at Object.exports.run (/home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-all.js:318:10)
    at doRunCommand [as func] (/home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/commands.js:347:17)
    at /home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js:1353:23
    - - - - -
    at null._onTimeout (/home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/commands-cordova.js:1211:22)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
%% Done clearing Android logs.
%% Tailing logs for android with `adb logcat -s CordovaLog`
%% Running asynchronously:  /home/tokam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1ahmcpn++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/adb.sh [ 'logcat', '-s', 'CordovaLog' ]
%% Done execing cordova for platform android-device

Could not start the app on your device. Is it plugged in?
Try running again with the --verbose option.
Instructions for running your app on an Android device:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-run-your-app-on-an-Android-device
```

Before running meteor **adb devices** lists:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
506c09aa    device
```

After running meteor **adb devices** tells me:

```
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error:
```

I already [changed the adb timeout rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout) to 12000ms.
My device is set up for development.

**How can I run an android app with meteor cordova?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the ANDROID_HOME environment variable on my ubuntu system.

Make sure to adjust the path corrosponding to your machine's setup.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/your-name/your/path/here/Android/android-sdk-linux_x86
```

[Do **not** point the variable to the platform-tools folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182550/cant-build-cordova-projects).